# MojoFailureException

Tags: maven, spring-boot

есть аннотация перед классом конфигурации в буте

```
@SpringBootApplication

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { //
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, //
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, //
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SbHibernateShoppingCartApplication {

}
```

когда аннотации имеются

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { //
            DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, //
            DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, //
            HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
```

у меня при нажатии на символ бина в идее на классах типа WebSecurityConfig идея пишет No matching beans found и при запуске вылетает с ошибкой что нет бинов

а когда я эти аннотации удаляю то мавен не может собрать проект

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\yuri\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\yuri\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] /C:/Users/yuri/SbHibernateShoppingCart/src/main/java/org/o7planning/sbshoppingcart/entity/Order.java:[6,25] package javax.persistence does not exist
```

и таких ошибок очень много впадает.

в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам надо добавить `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` в зависимости

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```